# Rendering Flame annimation on transparent background

Tags: fire

I am trying to render a burning object in fron of transparent background with blender 2.82. When I render with a transparent background the flames are not visible beyond the borders of the object, while with a black background I see the complete flames how I intended them to be.
How can I get visible flames beyond the object on the transparent background?
Example:
Here with transparent background
[image]
Here with black background the flames go beyond the object. 
[image]

Blendfile is attached [image]